# How can I make a button be used repeatedly to make text fields appear one by one using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is the current code I am using:

```
class Opening(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Opening, self).__init__()
        loadUi("reminder2.ui", self)
        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)



    def gotomain(self):
        main = MainWindow()
        widget.addWidget(main)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("reminder.ui",self)
        self.typebutton.clicked.connect(self.med)
        self.searchbutton.clicked.connect(self.medd)
        self.med2.hide()
        self.med3.hide()
        self.med4.hide()
        self.med5.hide()
        self.med6.hide()
        self.med7.hide()
        self.med8.hide()
        self.addbutton.clicked.connect(self.clickAdd)






    def med(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.typemed)


    def medd(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.searchmed)

    def clickAdd(self):
            self.med2.show()
```

Comment: You should use a QStackedWidget, which allows to switch between pages, just like you're doing for the top level window of your program. About that, be aware that you're probably basing your script on a youtube tutorial that is known to provide a lot of terrible suggestions, such as adding QDialogs to QStackedWidget and creating new pages every time instead of reusing them. I strongly suggest to ignore that tutorial, look for other resources and study the documentation of the classes you're using.

Comment: Okay I will try that out thanks